# My add to system path script keeps messing with the path unpredictably

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I made this nice batch that should add given path to system `%PATH%` on Windows:

```
@echo off
if exist %1\ (
   setx PATH "%PATH%;%1"
) else (
   echo %1 is NOT a folder
   pause
)
```

The `exist %1\` is a trick to check whether path is folder. I even made a nice context menu item for it:

[image: image description]

But the problem is it creates huge mess of repeated entries in system path. You might notice that I omitted `/M` parameter. That's on purpose, I want to configure **user's system path** only. That said I suppose I also need to be able to obtain that path specifically. At this moment I think it merges system and user path and does some additional mysterious mess.

Comment: I think you need to edit it in the registry, as a `cmd` instance merges system and user `PATH`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to clean path, you can add the following line `pathmgr.cmd /clean /user /y` to your batch and download [PathMgr](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4b83aee49c476af9cd8d) batch script from [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Batch-Script-To-Manage-7d0ef21e) or [here (gist)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4b83aee49c476af9cd8d)

```
>pathmgr /clean /user /?

CLEAN
Will clean up the PATH variable in the registry by removing
trailing and leading spaces, remove any enclosing double quotes,
remove duplicate paths and if /v specified will remove invalid paths.
The scope indicates wheteher user, system or both paths are cleaned.
By default will prompt if you want to make a permanaent
change to the registry. Note that any changes made to the path variable
not made permanent in the registry will be lost.
If you do not have administrator privileges you will not be able
to make changes to the system path.

SYNTAX:         pathmgr /clean [scope] [modifiers]

[scope]         /user|/system|/all

[modifiers]      /v Will also delete any invalid paths
                 /p Display prompt to make registry change.
                 /y Do not ask, just make registry change (batch mode).
                 /n Do not make registry change (batch mode).
```

And it can do many more.

```
pathmgr Version 1.0.2
Tool to manage the PATH environment variable.
Provides tools to add to , delete from, clean up,
backup and restore the PATH environment variable
either on a session basis or make permanent changes
in the registry. To get help type "pathmgr /?".
Whenever pathmgr is run a temporary environment
variable pathmgr_PATH is created that holds the
current path of the pathmgr command file. The
/path switch may be used to add the path of pathmgr itself.

SYNTAX:         pathmgr [/?|-?|] [action][modifier][scope][path]

[/?|-?]         Display help, further help can be obtained on
                a topic by including an action switch.
                Example: pathmgr /? /List  will provide help on list action.

[action]        The management action to perform. Perermited values are:-
                /list | /add | /del[ete] | /clean |/backup | /restore | /refresh | /path | /[env]ironment

[modifier]      Some actions may have additional options.
                         /x: Expand environment variables.
                         /r: Reverse order.
                         /v: validate a path(s) existence.
                        /nv: no validation of path(s) existence.
                         /p: display all prompts
                         /y: hide prompts and choose yes
                         /n: hide prompts and choose no
                         /+: add current pathmgr to PATH
                         /-: delete current pathmgr from PATH

[scope]         The scope within the registry to perform the action.
                Permited values are:-  /user | /system | /all.
                The default scope is user as there are fewer
                policy restrictions. System and All scopes may require
                administrative privileges.

[path]          Depending on context this will be either a folder or file path.
                If the path is the only argument then the default action is /add.
                Environment variables may be used in paths. The easiest way to do this
                is to enclose the variable name within question marks '?' rather than
                using the percent sign '', as an example ?systemroot?.
                This practice has the advantage of working either from the commandline or
                working within a batch. The alternative is to escape the variable as below.
                If used on the command line use:-  pathmgr /add ?systemroot?" or
                pathmgr /add "^%systemroot^%". If used within a batch use
                pathmgr /add   "?systemroot?" or pathmgr /add "%%systemroot%%".
                If these escaped paths are not used the path will be expanded prior to being
                interpreted so if you really want the path to be C:\Windows without escaping
                the path will be added as "c:\windows".
```

Comment: Ok, this works, the specific command to expand user path was: `pathmgr /add /y /user %1`